# MySQL where clauses with condition to display specific age

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

All Mysql query seems to work perfect expect condition for 'age' from my table. for example i need age to filter this condition from `age >=20` to `age <=30`, everting seems to work but not age.

for example check the link here [a link](http://shaadimubarakh.com/display_Search.php)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `file_records` 
           WHERE  (`country` = '$country' OR '$country' IS NULL) 
               OR (`gender` = '$gender' OR'$gender' IS NULL) 
               OR (`cast` = '$cast' OR '$cast' IS NULL) 
               OR (
                   (`age` >= '$age_from' OR   '$age_from' IS NULL) 
                     AND (`age` <= '$age_to' OR '$age_to' IS NULL)
                  ) 
           LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you choose between and operator for age like this format

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE age
BETWEEN age >=20 and age <=30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) function like

```
age BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking >= for both from and to date.. Try this..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `file_records` 
         WHERE (`country` = '$country' OR '$country' IS NULL) 
           OR (`gender` = '$gender' OR' $gender' IS NULL) 
           OR (`cast` = '$cast' OR '$cast' IS NULL) 
           OR ((`age` >= '$age_from' OR '$age_from' IS NULL) 
                AND (`age` <= '$age_to' OR '$age_to' IS NULL)) 
         LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you `echo $sql;`, you would see that it's impossible for
   `'' IS NULL` to be true.

you want something like

```
OR ((`age` >= '$age_from' OR '$age_from' = '') 
            AND (`age` <= '$age_to' OR '$age_to' = ''))
```